# go pass dynamically created function as parameter

Tags: function, go, closures

Ok. I have some trouble understanding what exactly is going on here with "MyPrinter"
Let me go step by step (please correct me if got something wrong) 
1. The "Salute" structure is created 
2. Call to "Greet" function 
2.a Call to "CreatePrinterFunction" with the strgin "!!!". This function returns a "MyPrinter" (witch is a function that takes in a string and returns nothing)
3. the variables "message" and "defaultMessage" are set with the strings

Now here's the problem, I don't understand what exactly are those do("str") doing

```
package main
import "fmt"

type Salute struct {
    name string
    greeting string
}

type MyPrinter func (s string) ()

func Greet(salute Salute, do MyPrinter) {
    message, defaultMessage := CreateMessage(salute.name, salute.greeting, "noName")
    do(message)
    do(defaultMessage)
}

func Print(s string) {
    fmt.Print(s)
}
func PrintLine(s string) {
    fmt.Println(s)
}

func CreatePrinterFunction(custom string) MyPrinter {
    return func (s string) {
        fmt.Println(s + custom)
    }
}

func CreateMessage(name string, greeting ...string) (message string, defaultMessage string) {
    message = name + " " + greeting[0]
    defaultMessage = "hey " + name
    return
}

func main() {
    var s = Salute{"Joe", "hello"}
    // Greet(s, PrintLine)
    Greet(s, CreatePrinterFunction("!!!"))
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CreatePrinterFunction` returns a [function literal](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Function_literals):

```
return func (s string) {
    fmt.Println(s + custom)
}
```

That function literal implements the MyPrinter interface, which is an interface implemented by any function that takes a string argument and returns nothing:

```
type MyPrinter func(s string)
```

(note that the `MyPrinter` definition in the provided snippet includes an extra `()` at the end which does nothing)

Then, that function created which implements the MyPrinter interface is passed as the `do` parameter of the `Greet` function:

```
func Greet(salute Salute, do MyPrinter) {
```

When code inside `Greet` runs `do(message)`, the created function literal is called, which in its turn runs the equivalent of `fmt.Println(message + custom)`.

It's a pretty convoluted way to do something simple. :-)

Comment: what does "do MyPrinter" mean. is it looking specifically for a function that gets a string and returns a function of type "MyPrinter" or just a function that will get a string and return nothing.What will happen if there is more than one function that returns "MyPrinter"

Comment: `do MyPrinter` simply means that the function accepts a parameter named `do` which must implement interface `MyPrinter`. You can have as many functions implementing a `MyPrinter` interface as you want, and any of them may be provided as that parameter to the function.

Comment: Ok, now I got it. I thought that `type MyPrinter` works like `define` in C, PHP, but it seams to create a new type of variable like `int, string`, this `type` seems to behave like a Class